# What do you call the sediment of brewed tea at the bottom of a cup or a teapot?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the sediment of (unstrained brewed) tea (or any other herbs) settles at the bottom of the cup or the teapot?

I have found the word "[**dregs**"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dregs) but I don't know if it can be used for tea or not.

PS:

I know that ["coffee ***grounds***"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coffee+grounds)is another term for those sediments in a cup of coffee.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dregs simply means

> the ​small ​solid ​pieces that ​sink to the ​bottom of some ​liquids, such as ​wine or ​coffee, that are not usually ​drunk:

You could certainly refer to the remnants of tea using the same term, and there are several instances online of this (7,750 results on google).

However, a lot of Brits would instead refer to them as **tea leaves**, using the same term for the remains as for the substance used to make the beverage in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @John Clifford. If the tea is strained well and there is no residue (?) inside it, can I call what remains at the bottom of the cup again "dregs" ? Like in " I don't like to drink my tea until the last drop, there is always some dregs  left in my cup.

Comment: I would consider that fine, and unambiguous in its meaning.

Comment: I see.@John Clifford. And my last questions: (1) Does "dreg" have a negative connotation too? (II mean  does "tea dregs" mean "leftover tea" too?) (2): Is it better to use "tea leaves" than "tea dregs"? :)

Comment: If you're concerned about connotations, it may perhaps be better to use "tea leaves" as dregs does tend to sound rather unpleasant by definition: it's "the bits you didn't want to drink".

Answer (score 1):

Dregs describes both liquids and solids left at the bottom of a cup or glass- basically anything you don't want to drink. It can also be used about wine or coffee.

It does have a distinctly negative connotation: it can be used in expression like "the dregs of society", referring to people of very low status- criminals, homeless people, et cetera. You can make allusions to this by referring to someone as "the dregs": this is deeply offensive.

As long as it's clear that you are talking about the contents of a cup, it's a perfectly acceptable term to use.